# one windows 10 pc with wired keyboard/mouse and one dell windows 7 both connected to a single split screen monitor

Tags: windows-10

question?

will synergy support a windows 10 pro pc with the keyboard and mouse wired connected to router by wireless ac pci adapter

I want to share this with a dell optiplex running windows 7 pro that is connected to the router buy a ethernet cable

Both pcs are plugged into an lg ultrawide monitor by hdmi (1 & 2)  which supports PBP i.e can show both sources on screen at the same time.

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems that as long as you are able to connect both computers, it should work. Windows 10 and 7 are both compatible according to the FAQ. Otherwise, you should probably ask Synergy.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have a windows 7 laptop, a Macbook Pro, and a windows 10 gaming pc. I have used Synergy on all three of these computers for a few years now. I've only recently ran into installation problems on windows 7 with the release of Synergy Pro 2 beta. You shouldn't have any problems.